# why the cross entropy loss of mnist classification using tensorflow's estimator high-level API and raw API are different in scale?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am reading some tensorflow example codes and I find the loss in [CNN-using-estimatorAPI](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/3_NeuralNetworks/convolutional_network.ipynb) and the loss in [raw CNN](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/3_NeuralNetworks/convolutional_network_raw.ipynb) are really different in scale, but they are all the same loss function:

the former is `loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits_train, labels=tf.cast(labels, dtype=tf.int32)))`, which use the not-one-hot label.

the latter is `loss_op =tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=Y))` , which use the one-hot vector label.

why the former loss is nearlly 0 ~ 2.39026, and the latter loss is much bigger, why is it?

Answer (score 1):

I know, it is because of the variable initializer difference, the default for tf.layers.* are not tf.random_normal(), for the bigger loss, it is because the internal processing mechanisum for log(0) in the softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits, I think the lower loss is more accurate, because log(1e-5)=-11.